How can I prevent unauthorized Bluetooth connections to my ESP32 device using Flutter Blue Plus?
I have built a Flutter application that connects to an ESP32 IoT device using the Flutter Blue Plus package. My primary goal is to ensure that only my Flutter app can connect and communicate with the ESP32 device, preventing any other apps or devices from establishing a connection.
Specifically, I would like to know:

What security measures can I implement on the ESP32 to restrict Bluetooth connections to only my Flutter app?
Are there any specific features or configurations in Flutter Blue Plus that can help enforce this restriction?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations on securing the Bluetooth connection effectively.

I want to configure my ESP32 device to only accept Bluetooth connections from my Flutter app using Flutter Blue Plus. My expectation is to restrict access so that no other devices or apps can connect. However, I noticed that other apps, like Serial Bluetooth Terminal, can still connect and write data to it. I'm unsure what steps to take to secure the connection and prevent unauthorized access. I need guidance on how to implement effective security measures.

This is not possible. Ultimately bytes on the wire (i.e. over bluetooth) are just bytes. There is no way to know if they come from your app or some other source. The best you can do is obfuscation. The most simple form is just challenge/response. Create a random AES key known by the device and your app. When an app connects to your device, the device responds with a challenge (8 random bytes). The app encrypts those bytes with the key and returns them. The device decrypts the response and ensures it matches. If not, it disconnects.
There are attacks against this, most significantly an attack called "machine in the middle" and of course someone can reverse engineer your app to extract the key. There are attacks against every automated attempt to prove that the other party is "trusted." But it is the starting point. But there is no actual solution. If there were, then things like "jailbreaking" would be impossible.
If this is a very valuable connection, then you will need to hire someone with background in obfuscation techniques to implement something more robust. More robust solutions (broadly called "hardening") are always custom, or at the very least expensive, because they are just obfuscation and so they can't be described in public. If someone else knew the secret, they could break it. True security techniques can ensure that the user is trusted, by checking that they know a password or have a physical device or the like. They might prove that the device is trusted if you can control all the devices involved. But they cannot prove that an app is trusted on hardware you do not control.
